# implement image slide animation on android, how to calculate pixels when each onDraw() invoked by duration

Tags: android

I want to implement an image slider like ViewPager in Android, I do the animation such as from left to right when onDraw invoke, this animation will be many times drawing till the target image was draw complete.
I set the slide duration, I want the animation finish when times up, but I don't know how much time spending for each onDraw(), before I start animation, I'll calculate pixels for each draw, after that, I invoke invalidate() method, the method will be lots of invoke till the image draw at top0&left0 position.
My question is, how to calculate the pixels for each draw. please give me some advices, thank you in advance.

Comment: Why not just use `ViewPager` with `ImageViews`?

Comment: I want keep good-looking at all version of Android, I also have some customization, for example, draw slider pagination at bottom. @MaciejGórski

Comment: ViewPager is part of the android support v4 library. That means it will work down from 1.6(api 4) and up. See here: http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html